# I have a Java Swing GUI as a .jar, how do I add it to my site as an HTML embed?

Tags: java, html, swing, jar

I know super general questions are frowned upon but I really don't know how else to figure this out. I made a java swing GUI (I'll drop the code at the bottom) that works as an estimator for construction jobs. It runs just fine in Eclipse where I wrote it, but I am trying to figure out how to embed the GUI in my website. I use square online for my web building, and they have a feature where you can add code; there isn't a lot of documentation for that but it seems like it wants the embed to be written in HTML. I have been trying to get some resources to help me out with this, but everything I've seen either depends on something that doesn't work anymore or leaves out important details.

I made the GUI into a .jar file through Eclipse, and I can see it downloaded on my OS, but that's as far as I've gotten. I have OpenWebStart installed as well per one of the resources I used, but I honestly don't know how to use it and can't figure that out either.

I am not sure if this is a hard or easy thing to do in general so sorry if I'm asking a lot. If you know any good documentation I can use to make this happen, just a link will do. Thanks!

Code: (NOTE: the GUI main function references a different file in the same folder one time, not sure if I need to add that in the embed somehow, I'll add it below the code just in case,)

```
package packagepackage;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet.ColorAttribute;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public JLabel tLabel;

        public JTextField linear;
        public JLabel liLabel;

        public JComboBox<String> sump;
        public JLabel suLabel;

        public JComboBox<String> elec;
        public JLabel elLabel;

        public JTextField prep;
        public JLabel prLabel;

        public JTextField estimate;
        public JLabel esLabel;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
            }
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            String title = "Craftsman Peak Drain Tile Calculator";
            tLabel = new JLabel(title, JLabel.CENTER);
            tLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 0.5;
            c.ipady = 40;
            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            add(tLabel, c);

            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridx = 0;

            liLabel = new JLabel("Basement Perimeter Length (ft.):");
            liLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            prLabel = new JLabel("Time needed to prepare site (min.):");
            prLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            suLabel = new JLabel("Using:");
            suLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            elLabel = new JLabel("Electrical outlet:");
            elLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            add(liLabel, c);
            c.gridy++;
            add(prLabel, c);
            c.gridy++;
            add(suLabel, c);
            c.gridy++;
            add(elLabel, c);

            linear = new JTextField(10);
            linear.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            linear.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            
            prep = new JTextField(10);
            prep.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            prep.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            
            String[] sumpo = {"New sump pump", "Existing sump pump"};
            sump = new JComboBox<>(sumpo);
            sump.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            sump.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            
            String[] electo = {"There is no outlet within 6 feet of the sump pump", "There is an outlet nearby, or I do not need a new pump"};
            elec = new JComboBox<>(electo);
            elec.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            elec.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            c.gridx++;
            c.gridy = 1;
            add(linear, c);
            c.gridy++;
            add(prep, c);
            c.gridy++;
            add(sump, c);
            c.gridy++;
            add(elec, c);

            JButton calculate = new JButton("Calculate");
            calculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Integer linVar = Integer.parseInt(linear.getText());
                    Integer feet = Integer.parseInt(linear.getText());
                    linVar *= 13;
                    
                    Object sumps = sump.getSelectedItem();
                    Integer sumpVar = 0;
                    if("New sump pump".equals(sumps)) {
                        sumpVar += 260;}
                    
                    Object elecs = elec.getSelectedItem();
                    Integer elecsVar = 0;
                    if("There is no outlet within 6 feet of the sump pump".equals(elecs)) {
                        elecsVar += 280;}
                    
                    Integer prepsVar = Integer.parseInt(prep.getText());
                    prepsVar += 30;
                    prepsVar *= 235;
                    prepsVar /= 100;
                    
                    linVar += sumpVar += elecsVar += prepsVar;
                    /* overhead*/
                    linVar += 2828;
                    /* tax */
                    linVar *= 11;
                    linVar /= 10;
                    /* margin */
                    linVar *= 12;
                    linVar /= 10;
                    /* adjustments*/
                    Integer adjOne = 300;
                    Integer adjTwo = adjOne -= feet;
                    adjTwo *= 2;
                    adjTwo += 100;
                    linVar += adjTwo;
                    
                    String toWords = " $" + String.valueOf(linVar);
                     
                        estimate.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI(toWords, true));
                        }

            });

            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
            c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 5;
            add(calculate, c);
            calculate.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            calculate.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            
            c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 6;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;

            esLabel = new JLabel("Estimated Cost:");
            esLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            estimate = new JTextField(10);
            estimate.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            estimate.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

            add(esLabel, c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = 1;
            add(estimate, c);
//            linear.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI("Perimeter length", true));
//            prep.setUI(new HintTextFieldUI("Minutes of preptime", true));
        }
    }
}
```

```
package packagepackage; 

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
    import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

    import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextFieldUI;
    import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;


    public class HintTextFieldUI extends BasicTextFieldUI implements FocusListener {

        private String hint;
        private boolean hideOnFocus;
        private Color color;

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
            repaint();
        }

        private void repaint() {
            if(getComponent() != null) {
                getComponent().repaint();           
            }
        }

        public boolean isHideOnFocus() {
            return hideOnFocus;
        }

        public void setHideOnFocus(boolean hideOnFocus) {
            this.hideOnFocus = hideOnFocus;
            repaint();
        }

        public String getHint() {
            return hint;
        }

        public void setHint(String hint) {
            this.hint = hint;
            repaint();
        }
        public HintTextFieldUI(String hint) {
            this(hint,false);
        }

        public HintTextFieldUI(String string, boolean hideOnFocus) {
            this(string,hideOnFocus, null);
        }

        public HintTextFieldUI(String hint, boolean hideOnFocus, Color color) {
            this.hint = hint;
            this.hideOnFocus = hideOnFocus;
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintSafely(Graphics g) {
            super.paintSafely(g);
            JTextComponent comp = getComponent();
            if(hint!=null && comp.getText().length() == 0 && (!(hideOnFocus && comp.hasFocus()))){
                if(color != null) {
                    g.setColor(color);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(comp.getForeground().brighter().brighter().brighter());              
                }
                int padding = (comp.getHeight() - comp.getFont().getSize())/2;
                g.drawString(hint, 2, comp.getHeight()-padding-1);          
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            if(hideOnFocus) repaint();

        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if(hideOnFocus) repaint();
        }
        @Override
        protected void installListeners() {
            super.installListeners();
            getComponent().addFocusListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        protected void uninstallListeners() {
            super.uninstallListeners();
            getComponent().removeFocusListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'The way' used to be 'applets'. But applets were deprecated and removed from the API in Java 9. Javascript is good for doing the underlying work with web interfaces. **Edit:** *"I have OpenWebStart installed"* the more accurate way to say my first comment is that the Java Plug-In (which allows both applets and webstart was deprecated. so that's no use either. *"I am not sure if this is a hard or easy thing to do"* Not so much 'hard' or 'easy' as not doable.

Comment: So if applets and webstart don't work anymore, how can I embed my java GUI? Do I need to rewrite the whole thing in JS then? I guess I'm confused cause if people still write stuff in Java IDE's then how do they actually implement the code then?

Comment: Huh? I asked how to do something, you said its not doable, and what I'm trying to figure out is what I have to do then in order to achieve my goal of putting the GUI I built in my website as an embed

Comment: One of us is very confused. Possibly both of us. OTOH only one of us actually cares if you achieve this. For my part, I'm too busy to get into sorting the mess out.

Comment: You can't embed your Swing GUI in a web page.  It's impossible for too many reasons to explain here.  It's impossible.  Did I mention, it's impossible.